# A simple proof for sum of intersection multiplicities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory

The definition for intersection multiplicity used in Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* is given by:

$$I(P,F\cap G):=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathscr{O}_{P,\mathbb{A}^2}/(F,G)),$$

(see section 3.3) where $\mathscr{O}_{P,\mathbb{A}^2}$ denotes the local ring of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at $P$.

Later, Fulton proves a property (Property (9)) about intersection multiplicity:

$$\sum_{P}I(P,F\cap G)=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(F,G)).$$

However, the proof of this result refers to an earlier result, which Fulton gave a proof which is a bit complicated (see section 2.9; it refers to several earlier results and exercises, as well as using some tools like "higher" tools Radical).

I want to know if there's a simpler way of showing that $\sum_{P}I(P,F\cap G)=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(F,G))$ without using tools like Radicals, etc, or does the nature of this result demands a not-simple proof?

Or, since there's "only one intersection multiplicity", is there another way of defining intersection multiplicity which makes this result easier to proof (but without referring to resultant)?

Edit: I am actually preparing a short talk for a seminar course, where most of us have only taken a one-year undergrad algebra course, which, as far as I know, does not cover topics like local rings, radicals, etc. However, basics of Noetherian and Artinian rings are introduced (so at least they know what Noetherian and Artinian rings are, and I believe I can use this as a starting point).

Comment: I mean $k[x,y]/(F,G)$ is an Artinian ring, and thus is isomorphic to the product of its local rings, which are the local rings defining the intersection number. But I suspect you might not consider this a simple proof.

Comment: Relatedly, it would help if you said a bit about your background in algebra/commutative algebra/ring theory/polynomials, etc. Otherwise it will be very difficult for us to provide an answer that will be helpful to you.

Comment: @jgon Would you mind opening an answer and elaborating on that? I am quite interested in that proof. (I saw this way of proving it in a Chinese textbook, but the notation and word choice are so weird that I cannot understand it. But I believe this is a way of proving it.)

Comment: @jgon I added a background description.